# Published rates from UPS shipments API?

Tags: ups, ups-api

I am trying to make a UPS shipments API request for my client and get back the *published* rates, not the negotiated rates.  Do you know how to do this?  In the response, I can see we are getting a different "RateChart" with my client's UPS account as opposed to my own personal UPS account.  I have tried various `ShipmentRatingOptions` in the request (and no `ShipmentRatingOptions` at all), but this makes no difference as to the rates I am receiving.